# Prepend a column in CSV File in Linux by passing parameters

Tags: linux, csv

I would like to prepend a column in CSV File in Linux by passing parameters in at run time.

For example my input File `Input.csv` has the following contents:

```
abc,Nodes.csv
def,Nodes.csv
ghi,Nodes.csv
jkl,Nodes.csv
```

Now I would like to pass a parameter in at run time while running the script like `./Datafile.sh CRE_ff`

The output file should look like this:

```
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,abc,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,def,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,ghi,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,jkl,Nodes.csv
```

Comment: please explain a bit more how the name `CRE_ff_Nodes_abc` is composed ... In your example output it's the same for all lines ... And please show us what you tried, as there are similar questions around, and it should be fairly easy to find an answer...

Answer (score 0):

We can create a `csvprepend` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN  { field=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]; OFS=","}
       { print field,$0 }
```

and use it:

```
$ chmod 755 cvsprepend               # turn it in an executable command
$ cvsprepend "New field" old.csv
New Field,abc,Nodes.csv
New Field,def,Nodes.csv
```

details:

- `field=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]`    saves the first commandline arg. as `field`
- `OFS=","`         sets output field separator
- `print field,$0`    prints the new field, OFS, previous record.

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below awk and sed command.Python and it worked fine

awk solution:

```
awk  '{print "CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,"$0}' filename
```

output

```
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,abc,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,def,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,ghi,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,jkl,Nodes.csv
```

command2:

```
sed "s/^/CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,/g" filename
```

output

```
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,abc,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,def,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,ghi,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,jkl,Nodes.csv
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
o=open('filename','r')
for i in o:
    print "CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,{0}".format(i).strip()
```

output

```
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,abc,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,def,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,ghi,Nodes.csv
CRE_ff_Nodes_abc,jkl,Nodes.csv
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear, but your answer does not do the part that *is* clear: "Now I would like to pass a parameter in at run time while running the script like `./Datafile.sh CRE_ff`". Your answer would also benefit from *explaining* what your commands do, although honestly I wouldn't even bother answering until the question is clarified.